The closure of the space of Riemannian metrics with a fixed isometry class
Let $M$ be a closed manifold, and let $\mathscr{M}$ be the space of all Riemannian metrics over $M$. It is known that this is a Fréchet manifold. Consider also $\mathscr{D}$ the diffeomorphisms group of $M$. It acts upon $\mathscr{M}$ by pullback.
It is well known Ebin70 that the set of Riemannian metrics with no nontrivial isometries is dense in $\mathscr{M}$. Here I ask if this result can be generalized:
Given $g\in \mathscr{M}$, let $I_{g}=\{\varphi\in \mathscr{D}\,|\,\varphi^{*}g=g\}$, i.e., the isometry group of $g$. Let $\mathscr{M}_{(I_{g})}\subseteq \mathscr{M}$ be the set,
$$
\mathscr{M}_{(I_{g})}=\{\gamma\in\mathscr{M}\,|\,\exists\varphi\in\mathscr{D}\,\,s.t.\, \varphi\circ I_{\gamma}\circ \varphi^{-1}=I_{g}\}
$$
i.e., the set of all Riemannian metrics with a fixed isometry class under conjugaction.
The aforementioned fact reads $\overline{\mathscr{M}_{(\mathrm{Id})}}=\mathscr{M}$.
My question is: what is $\overline{\mathscr{M}_{(I_{g})}}=?$

I suspect that the answer is the space
$$
\mathscr{M}_{\geq (I_{g})}=\{\gamma\in\mathscr{M}\,|\,\exists\varphi\in\mathscr{D}\,\,s.t.\, \varphi\circ I_{\gamma}\circ \varphi^{-1}\geq I_{g}\}
$$
It can be proven that $\mathscr{M}_{(I_g)}$ is open in this set. However, when I tried to adapt the proof Ebin70 to this setting I failed.

EDIT: Following Peter Michor insightful answer, I add here an analgous situation where the above result is true. I would like to understand what is the fundamental difference between these situations, if possible. The example is taken from Sec.4.3 in KR86.
Consider a principle bundle $P$, and let $\mathscr{G}$ be the group of automorphisms on $P$. Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the space of connections on $P$. In the above notations, replacing $\mathscr{M}$ with $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ with $\mathscr{G}$, it is shown in KR86, Thm.4.3.5 that $\overline{\mathscr{C}_{(I_{A})}}=\mathscr{C}_{\geq(I_{A})}$, where $A\in\mathscr{C}$ is a connection.

$\overline{\mathscr{M}_{(I_{g})}}$ is a subset of $\mathscr{M}_{\geq (I_{g})}$. Not every smaller stratum (with larger isotropy group) has to be in the boundary of ${\mathscr{M}_{(I_{g})}}$.
My guess is: Only those ${\mathscr{M}_{(I_{g_1})}}$ are in the boundary of ${\mathscr{M}_{(I_{g})}}$ where ${(I_{g})}$ is in the boundary ${(I_{g_1})}$ as subsets of $\mathscr{D}$; and probably one even has to distinguish between connected components of conjugacy classes and/or isotropy groups in special cases.

Thank you. If I may ask, can the thing that makes the property $\overline{\mathscr{M}{(I{g})}}=\mathscr{M}{\geq(I{g})}$ fail be specified? I ask this becuase in quite a  similar setting, taken from gauge theory, it is known that the action of automorphisms on the space of connections actually does satisfy this property, even though the action is not free and has a compact istropy group in general.
